# C++ Debugging; I can't see a mistake :(

Tags: c++

So usually after a night of "drinking", I come home and check the level of drunkenness by programming. I decided to make a calculator program. I got an error, and now I can't go to sleep. Can someone please remove me from this misery. What is wrong with this code?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double num1;
    double num2;
    char redo;
    char operation;
    do
      {  
         cout<< "Please enter your calculation "<< endl;
         cin >> num1 >> operation >>num2;
         switch operation {
           case '+':
             cout<< "" <<num1+num2 << endl;
             break;

           case '/':
             cout<< "" <<num1/num2 << endl;
             break;

           case '*':
             cout<< "" <<num1*num2 << endl;
             break;

           case '/':
             cout<< "" <<num1/num2 << endl;
             break;

      }
      while (redo=='y'||redo=='Y');
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My first debug error is at the cout.. I haven't been able to sleep :(

---

YAY! I'm NOT drunk!! I got it to work!!! Thajink yoou giusy so mcuh!!
Oh, heres the code btw:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double num1;
    double num2;
    char redo;
    char operation;
    do
      {  
         cout<< "Please enter your calculation "<< endl;
         cin >> num1 >> operation >>num2;
         switch (operation) {
           case '+':
             cout<< num1+num2 << endl;
             break;

           case '-':
             cout<< num1-num2 << endl;
             break;

           case '*':
             cout<< num1*num2 << endl;
             break;

           case '/':
             cout<< num1/num2 << endl;
             break;

      }
     cout<<" Do you want to continue? ";
     cin>>redo; }

     while (redo=='y'||redo=='Y');
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Is it runtime error? or compile-time?

Comment: What error are you getting and what data are you entering?

Comment: I do not think this is related to the error, but why do you have 2 `/` operations? I think you need to go to bed man ;)

Comment: @Elalfer: good catch, that's certain to cause a compile error.  case values are required to be unique (it's rather handy for implementing `static_assert`, actually).

Comment: Check my version below. Seems you have lots of tiny errors confusing the compiler. (Honestly, it's a dumb question)

Comment: Well, one thing that's wrong with this code as a StackOverflow example is that you've neither reported the error message you get nor reduced it to a minimal example.  The purpose of StackOverflow is to answer questions, not debug your code for you.

Comment: This is rarely a good barometer of sobriety...

Comment: @SQL_Lover- Not to beg for reputation points or anything, but if you're satisfied with a particular answer you should accept it so that the question is marked as answered. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your program is missing a closing curly brace for the `switch` statement; I'm not sure if that's an error in copying the code to the post or if that's what's actually responsible for your woes.

On a somewhat unrelated note, I noticed that at a few spots in your code you've written

```
cout<< "" <<num1+num2 << endl;
```

You don't need to print the empty string before printing out the sum; you can just write

```
cout<< num1 + num2 << endl;
```

Another issue you might be having is that your code loops with this condition:

```
while (redo=='y'||redo=='Y');
```

However, your code never assigns a value to `redo`, so this has unspecified behavior - it could loop forever, or loop just once.

Hopefully this helps fix things up!

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I got it to work! ..so i'm totally not drunk

Answer (score 0):

Which `cout`?  You use it 5 times in your program.

You're reading `redo` without ever assigning a value to it.  That's not likely to work right.

Answer (score 0):

You seconda case should be a '-' not a '/'. There aren't enough closing parentheses.

This works for me:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double num1;
  double num2;
  char redo;
  char operation;
  do
  {
    cout<< "Please enter your calculation "<< endl;
    cin >> num1 >> operation >>num2;
    switch (operation )
      {
      case '+':
        cout<< "" <<num1+num2 << endl;
        break;

      case '-':
        cout<< "" <<num1-num2 << endl;
        break;

      case '*':
        cout<< "" <<num1*num2 << endl;
        break;

      case '/':
        cout<< "" <<num1/num2 << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
    while (redo=='y'||redo=='Y');
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Why 2nd, why not 4th? :D

Comment: The order is generally + ,-, *, /. But feel free to make your own ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Some bugs I could see:

1. There is a missing closing brace `}` for `switch` block.
2. The condition in switch should be in parenthesis:

   ```
   switch (operation) {
          ^         ^
   ```
3. There is duplicate `case '/'`. Case `-` is missing.
4. Variable `redo` is being used uninitialized. You need to ask user if he wants to continue. Read the response in variable `redo`.

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/5U9E1)